# How do I get an output with Stargazer?

Tags: python, regression, stargazer

I tried to create a regression table output using the Stargazer-Package. I did everything like the documentation said, but somehow I cant get it to work.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from IPython.display import display

from stargazer.stargazer import Stargazer

import statsmodels.api as sm



#Import

daten = pd.read_excel(r"G:\Meine Ablage\Kinga\Daten\Rice-Data.xlsx", sheet_name="Data")



#Festlegen des Regressands

Y = daten['yield']



### Komplett Regression

est = sm.OLS(endog=daten['yield'], exog=sm.add_constant(daten[daten.columns[4:8]])).fit()

est2 = sm.OLS(endog=daten['yield'], exog=sm.add_constant(daten[daten.columns[4:10]])).fit()



stargazer = Stargazer([est, est2])

stargazer
```

This is the error I get: Out[4]: <stargazer.stargazer.Stargazer at 0x1689be8e730>

How do I get it to run so that I can see the output (table with comparison)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try forcing jupyter notebook to render the HTML by

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML(stargazer.render_html())
```